# How to comment multiple images at once

Tags: metadata, batch, exif, exiftool

On Windows I had that nice bar on the bottom with the exif entries that I can't manage to make appear on Ubuntu (I'm on Lubuntu but I've tried Mate and Plasma 5.4 too).
I've tried with exiftool: `exiftool -Comment='my comment' <directory>` but once I check with gThumb, under Comment > Description there's nothing written. How can I batch comment a bunch of pictures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of [ExifTool FAQ #3](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/faq.html#Q3).  On a test photo, edit the description in gThumb with something unique, then use the command `exiftool -a -G1 -s FILE` to see what is the actual tag that is being edited.

I did some quick searches to try and see what metadata gThumb is actually editing but it was of little value.  I would suggest checking the Caption-Abstract, Description, and ImageDescription tags as those are the most likely tags that gThumb is reading for the Comment > Description.

edit: Found info that gThumb can read EXIF, IPTC, and XMP metadata, so it might be reading any or all of the above three tags I mentioned for its Description entry.  I'd suggest trying `exiftool -Description='my comment' <directory>` as your command.

edit 2:  I found [this post](http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/exiftool/forum/index.php?topic=3672.0) on the ExifTool forums that indicates that when writing, gThumb is probably using both Description and Caption-Abstract.  Description is part of the more modern XMP standard, so I suggest using the command in my first edit, though using Caption-Abstract is also an option.

Comment: `exiftool -Description='my comment' <directory>` worked. Thanks!